# Overloading insertion << operator

Tags: c++

Hello I am trying to overload the insertion operator but there is an error in my compiler when initializing it.

In the .h file

```
class Zfraction{
public:
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& display, Zfraction const& b);
}
```

in the .cpp

```
std::ostream& Zfraction::operator<<(std::ostream &display, Zfraction const& b){


}
```

There is the output

Overloaded 'operator<<' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: `friend` declaration declares a non-member function, so the definition should be `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &display, Zfraction const& b){ ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header in the `.cpp` file is wrong. By using the scope resolution operator, `::`, you're indicating that the operator that you're overloading is a member function of the `Zfraction` class. This is not true. Although `friend` declarations must take place inside of the class that they are establishing friendship with, they are not member functions (in other words, they don't have access to a `*this` pointer). Thus, you need to change the `.cpp` file to the following:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &display, Zfraction const& b){
   /* Provide your implementation here. */
}
```